# How to set up VNC Server in Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, vncviewer

I have 3 RPis running on my system. Two of them are set up with Raspian and the most recent one is set up with Ubuntu Mate (I have Mate on my laptop and really like it). With the two Raspian ones, I can easily VNC into them from my PC as VNC server comes as standard with Raspian. So my question is how do I set up VNC Server on the Pi using Mate, so that I can access all of them the same way?

Comment: What release of Ubuntu-MATE are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can head over to the [download](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/#) page of RealVNC Server, and download the armhf and arm64 versions for Ubuntu running in Raspberry Pi.

Here are the download links for the latest version.

After downloading, you can install it with the command

```
sudo apt install ./path/to/installer.deb
```

Alternatively, you can install the deb package graphically with the GDebi package installer.